# Android:- Contents are not getting displayed using the customized ListView

Tags: android

**Main Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ListView list;
    /*Take these values from the database*/

    String[] itemName={"Puma","Reebok","Fila","Unite Colors of Benetton","Addidas"};
    String[] itemDescription={"Puma Green Colour Shoes","Reebok Red Colour Shoes","Fila Brown Colour Shoes","Boat Shoes","Addidas black Colour Shoes"};
    Integer[] price={1000,2000,3000,4000,5000};
    Integer[] Discount={10,20,30,40,50};
    Integer[] sizeOption1={6,6,6,6,6};
    Integer[] sizeOption2={7,7,7,7,7};
    Integer[] sizeOption3={8,8,8,8,8};

    Integer[] imageId={R.drawable.shoeimage,R.drawable.shoeimage2,R.drawable.shoeimage3,
            R.drawable.shoeimage4,R.drawable.shoeimage5};
    CustomListItems customListObject;
    customListObject = new CustomListItems(MainActivity.this,itemName,imageId,itemDescription,
            price,Discount,sizeOption1,sizeOption2,sizeOption3);
    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewDisplay);
    list.setAdapter(customListObject);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

**Custom List Class is as below.**

```
public CustomListItems(Activity context,
        String[] itemName, 
        Integer[] imageId, 
        String[] itemDescription, 
        Integer[] price, 
        Integer[] discountValue,
        Integer[] sizeOption1,
        Integer[] sizeOption2, 
        Integer[] sizeOption3)
{
    super(context, R.layout.list_items_display);
    this.context=context;
    this.itemDescription=itemDescription;
    this.imageId=imageId;
    this.itemName=itemName;
    this.price=price;
    this.discountValue=discountValue;
    this.sizeOption1=sizeOption1;
    this.sizeOption2=sizeOption2;
    this.sizeOption3=sizeOption3;



}
@Override
public View getView(int position,View view, ViewGroup parent)
{
    LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_items_display, null, true);
    ImageView imgView= (ImageView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.list_image);
    TextView txtItemDescription=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtItemDiscription);
    TextView txtItemTitle=(TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtItemtitle);
    Button btnSizeOption1=(Button)rowView.findViewById(R.id.btnSize1);
    Button btnSizeOption2=(Button)rowView.findViewById(R.id.btnSize2);
    Button btnSizeOption3=(Button)rowView.findViewById(R.id.btnSize3);
    TextView txtPrice=(TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtPrice);
    TextView txtDiscountValue=(TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtDiscountValue);
    txtItemTitle.setText("Puma");
    txtItemDescription.setText("Black Color Shoes");
    txtPrice.setText("5000");
    txtDiscountValue.setText("50");
    btnSizeOption1.setText("6");
    btnSizeOption2.setText("7");
    btnSizeOption3.setText("8");
    imgView.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
    return rowView;


}

}
```

However nothing is getting displayed. I am new to Android.

Below are the XML files

List Items XML file

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtItemtitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"      
    android:textColor="#040404"
    android:typeface="sans"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtItemDiscription"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/txtDiscountValue"
    android:layout_below="@id/txtItemtitle"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
    android:textColor="#343434" />

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/txtSize"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btnSize3"
     android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnSize3"
     android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnSize3"
     android:text="Size"
     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/txtDiscountValue"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txtPrice"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/txtPrice"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtSize"
     android:layout_below="@+id/btnSize1"
     android:layout_marginTop="36dp"

     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

 <ImageView
     android:id="@+id/list_image"
     android:layout_width="20dp"
     android:layout_height="20dp"
     android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txtItemtitle"
     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtItemtitle"
     android:contentDescription="SampleImage" />

 <Button
     android:id="@+id/btnSize3"
     style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_below="@+id/txtItemDiscription"
     android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
     android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/txtItemDiscription" />

 <Button
     android:id="@+id/btnSize1"
     style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txtSize"
     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtItemDiscription" />

 <Button
     android:id="@+id/btnSize2"
     style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btnSize1"
     android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnSize1"
     android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnSize1" />
```

However list item view had only one list in it. Code is shown as below

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listViewDisplay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    >
</ListView>
```

Request you to please check.

Main activity look like as below

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSignIn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="128dp"
    android:text="@string/btnSignIn" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtWelcomeMessage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
    android:text="Welcome to shopping Cart"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnContinueShopping"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="37dp"
    android:text="@string/btnContinueShopping" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSignUp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btnSignIn"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnSignIn"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:text="@string/btnSignUp" />
```

I am using ArrayAdapter here and log cat shows some issue with height while fetching from the getView().

PFB the log cat.

08-16 04:32:47.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1991): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-16 04:32:47.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1991): Process: com.example.onlineshop, PID: 1991
08-16 04:32:47.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1991): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-16 04:32:47.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1991):     at com.example.onlineshop.CustomListItems.getView(CustomListItems.java:53)
08-16 04:32:47.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1991):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2263)
08-16 04:32:47.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1991):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1263)
08-16 04:32:47.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1991):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1175)
08-16 04:32:47.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1991):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16458)
08-16 04:32:47.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1991):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:689)
08-16 04:32:47.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1991):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:473)
08-16 04:32:47.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1991):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16458)
08-16 04:32:47.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1991):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
08-16 04:32:47.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1991):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
08-16 04:32:47.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1991):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16458)
08-16 04:32:47.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1991):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
08-16 04:32:47.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1991):     at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:327)
08-16 04:32:47.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1991):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16458)
08-16 04:32:47.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1991):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
08-16 04:32:47.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1991):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
08-16 04:32:47.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1991):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2289)
08-16 04:32:47.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1991):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16458)
08-16 04:32:47.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1991):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1914)
08-16 04:32:47.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1991):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1111)
08-16 04:32:47.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1991):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1293)
08-16 04:32:47.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1991):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:998)
08-16 04:32:47.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1991):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5582)
08-16 04:32:47.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1991):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
08-16 04:32:47.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1991):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
08-16 04:32:47.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1991):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
08-16 04:32:47.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1991):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
08-16 04:32:47.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1991):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
08-16 04:32:47.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1991):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-16 04:32:47.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1991):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-16 04:32:47.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1991):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
08-16 04:32:47.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1991):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-16 04:32:47.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1991):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)

Please if anybody can help here.

Comment: Does your getView() get called?  What does list_items_display.xml look like? What does activity_main.xml look like?

Comment: Hi Greg; Thanks for your reply. Yes getView() function is not getting called. I will post the list_items_display and activity_main xmls files today...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your custom adapter does not really have any items. You have not overridden `getCount()` and are not passing any objects to the `super` constructor (assuming the superclass is e.g. `ArrayAdapter`) so the superclass implementation cannot report the correct number of items in the adapter.

Comment: Hi laalto; Thanks for your reply. I had overridden the getcount also but my getview method is not getting invoked. Also I am passing the objects to super constructor now.

Answer (score 0):

which adapter do you extend???

change your getView to this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position,View view, ViewGroup parent)
{
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_items_display, parent, false);
    ImageView imgView= (ImageView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.list_image);
    TextView txtItemDescription=(TextView)  
    rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtItemDiscription);
    TextView txtItemTitle=(TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtItemtitle);
    Button btnSizeOption1=(Button)rowView.findViewById(R.id.btnSize1);
    Button btnSizeOption2=(Button)rowView.findViewById(R.id.btnSize2);
    Button btnSizeOption3=(Button)rowView.findViewById(R.id.btnSize3);
    TextView txtPrice=(TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtPrice);
    TextView txtDiscountValue=(TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtDiscountValue);
    txtItemTitle.setText("Puma");
    txtItemDescription.setText("Black Color Shoes");
    txtPrice.setText("5000");
    txtDiscountValue.setText("50");
    btnSizeOption1.setText("6");
    btnSizeOption2.setText("7");
    btnSizeOption3.setText("8");
    imgView.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
   return rowView;
```

}
 it's better use viewHolder for better performance.
this work for me:

```
public class Main extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ListView list;
    /* Take these values from the database */

    String[] itemName = { "Puma", "Reebok", "Fila",
            "Unite Colors of Benetton", "Addidas" };
    String[] itemDescription = { "Puma Green Colour Shoes",
            "Reebok Red Colour Shoes", "Fila Brown Colour Shoes",
            "Boat Shoes", "Addidas black Colour Shoes" };
    Integer[] price = { 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000 };
    Integer[] Discount = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 };
    Integer[] sizeOption1 = { 6, 6, 6, 6, 6 };
    Integer[] sizeOption2 = { 7, 7, 7, 7, 7 };
    Integer[] sizeOption3 = { 8, 8, 8, 8, 8 };

    Integer[] imageId = { R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher };
    final CustomListItems customListObject;
    customListObject = new CustomListItems(Main.this, itemName, imageId,
            itemDescription, price, Discount, sizeOption1, sizeOption2,
            sizeOption3);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewDisplay);
    list.setAdapter(customListObject);


    }
}
```

customAdapter.class

```
public class CustomListItems extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
private Activity context;
private String[] itemDescription;
private Integer[] imageId;
private String[] itemName;
private Integer[] price;
private Integer[] discountValue;
private Integer[] sizeOption1;
private Integer[] sizeOption2;
private Integer[] sizeOption3;

public CustomListItems(Activity context, String[] itemName,
        Integer[] imageId, String[] itemDescription, Integer[] price,
        Integer[] discountValue, Integer[] sizeOption1,
        Integer[] sizeOption2, Integer[] sizeOption3) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_items_display);
    this.context = context;
    this.itemDescription = itemDescription;
    this.imageId = imageId;
    this.itemName = itemName;
    this.price = price;
    this.discountValue = discountValue;
    this.sizeOption1 = sizeOption1;
    this.sizeOption2 = sizeOption2;
    this.sizeOption3 = sizeOption3;

}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return discountValue.length;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater
            .inflate(R.layout.list_items_display, null, true);
    ImageView imgView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.list_image);
    TextView txtItemDescription = (TextView) rowView
            .findViewById(R.id.txtItemDiscription);
    TextView txtItemTitle = (TextView) rowView
            .findViewById(R.id.txtItemtitle);
    Button btnSizeOption1 = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.btnSize1);
    Button btnSizeOption2 = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.btnSize2);
    Button btnSizeOption3 = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.btnSize3);
    TextView txtPrice = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtPrice);
    TextView txtDiscountValue = (TextView) rowView
            .findViewById(R.id.txtDiscountValue);
    txtItemTitle.setText("Puma");
    txtItemDescription.setText("Black Color Shoes");
    txtPrice.setText("5000");
    txtDiscountValue.setText("50");
    btnSizeOption1.setText("6");
    btnSizeOption2.setText("7");
    btnSizeOption3.setText("8");
    imgView.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
    return rowView;

   }

}
```

and main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.mhp.customimagebtn"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listViewDisplay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#fff" >

<TextView
android:id="@+id/txtItemtitle"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"      
android:textColor="#040404"
android:typeface="sans"
android:textStyle="bold"/>

<TextView
android:id="@+id/txtItemDiscription"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignRight="@+id/txtDiscountValue"
android:layout_below="@id/txtItemtitle"
android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
android:textColor="#343434" />

<TextView
 android:id="@+id/txtSize"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btnSize3"
 android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnSize3"
 android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnSize3"
 android:text="Size"
 android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

 <TextView
 android:id="@+id/txtDiscountValue"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txtPrice"
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

 android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

 <TextView
 android:id="@+id/txtPrice"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtSize"
 android:layout_below="@+id/btnSize1"
 android:layout_marginTop="36dp"

 android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

 <ImageView
 android:id="@+id/list_image"
 android:layout_width="20dp"
 android:layout_height="20dp"
 android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txtItemtitle"
 android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtItemtitle"
 android:contentDescription="SampleImage" />

 <Button
 android:id="@+id/btnSize3"
 style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_below="@+id/txtItemDiscription"
 android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
 android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
 android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/txtItemDiscription" />

 <Button
 android:id="@+id/btnSize1"
 style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txtSize"
 android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtItemDiscription" />

 <Button
 android:id="@+id/btnSize2"
 style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btnSize1"
 android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnSize1"
 android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
 android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnSize1" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

the result

[image]

Comment: Its not working I tried doing that. However logcat shows some height issue of the item. if you want I can share that....

Comment: I had put the logcat file.

Comment: I test your project it does not show anything but after adding @Override
 public int getCount() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return discountValue.length;
 } listview shown

Comment: Hi MHP, Thanks for your time. I will test this today only and I will post the result.

Comment: I tried everything. but it is not appearing. I tried to change the layout, tried to change the structure by creating a new class.

Comment: Thanks MHP. Thanks a lot. I am checking the difference in mine,

Answer (score 0):

Extend your CustomListItems Class with **BaseAdapter** like this

```
public CustomListItems extends BaseAdapter { ... }
```

Comment: But i want to use the ArrayAdapter. is there no way that arrayAdapter can go with it.

Comment: But as your CustomListItems Class is not extending to ether **BaseAdapter** or **ArrayAdapter**, so I suggest you to extend it with base adapter